# Need help understanding why creating a reference to $scope in a directive link function works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to understand why I need to write my function in a specific way for it to not throw an error. I'm not certain if this is an Angular thing, a Javascript thing, or a combination of both, but would love to get some help understanding this.

I have created a directive that creates a popover when the user selects some text. I'm specifically targeting the `mouseup` event and I'm setting it up in the directive's link function.

A simplified version of my directive looks like the following:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myPopOver', myPopOver);

myPopOver.$inject = [ '$http',
                      '$rootScope',
                      '$compile',
                      '$controller' ];

function myPopOver( $http, $rootScope, $compile, $controller ) {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link     : postLink,
        scope    : {
            popOverController   : '=',
            popOverControllerAs : '=',
            evidenceCollection  : '=',
            popOverTemplateUrl  : '=',
            minStringLength     : '=',
            enablePopOver       : '='
        }
    };

    function postLink( $scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller ) {
        var MIN_LENGTH;

        MIN_LENGTH = $scope.minimumStringLength != null ? $scope.minimumStringLength : 5;

        return iElement.on('mouseup', handleMouseUpEvent);

        function handleMouseUpEvent( event ) {
            var selectedText, meetsLengthRequirements, canDisplayPopOver;

            if ( $scope.enablePopOver === undefined ) {
                canDisplayPopOver = true;
            } else {
                canDisplayPopOver = $scope.enablePopOver;
            }
            selectedText            = window.getSelection();
            meetsLengthRequirements = selectedText.toString().length >= MIN_LENGTH;

            if ( !selectedText.isCollapsed && !activePopOver && meetsLengthRequirements && canDisplayPopOver) {
                return onTextSelect(event, selectedText);
            }
            else {
                return clearPopOver();
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

This version above works. However, when I initially created the function that would handle the `mouseup` event, I wrote it as follows:

```
function handleMouseUpEvent( event ) {
    var selectedText, meetsLengthRequirements;

    if ( $scope.enablePopOver === undefined ) {
        $scope.enablePopOver = true;
    } 

    selectedText            = window.getSelection();
    meetsLengthRequirements = selectedText.toString().length >= MIN_LENGTH;

    if ( !selectedText.isCollapsed && !activePopOver && meetsLengthRequirements && $scope.enablePopOver) {
        return onTextSelect(event, selectedText);
    }
    else {
        return clearPopOver();
    }
}
```

However, this version throws the Angular error:

```
Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'myPopOver' is non-assignable!
```

The details for the error can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign

I have the directive working, but not knowing the answer to this question is bothering me and I would love to improve my understanding of Angular and Javascript as well, depending on what ultimately was wrong with my original code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show us the HTML where you instanciate `my-pop-over` directive?

Comment: would help to point out the differences so we don't have to be human diff tools. Also a demo of failing code would help. Use angular production (not minified version)version for more verbose error output and stack traces

Comment: Yes, +1 @floribon. The error that is linked to is more about the "arguments" that you pass to the directive when you use it in the HTML template, not necessarily about how you wrote the link function. Using the example from the error page: `<my-directive bind="1+2">` the 1+2 expression cannot be updated via the scope of the directive, and is not two way "binadable".

Comment: the issue definitely is revolving around `$scope.enablePopOver`.  I still believe that it is not possible to create it from the isolate `$scope` if it is `undefined`, but others disagree.  If you can show how it is being assigned in the HTML, that would clear this up.

Comment: At this step in the process, I hadn't actually added the HTML attribute to the template. The idea behind this attribute was that it could be used if needed to monitor a boolean variable to determine whether to display the popOver or not. And if I didn't include the attribute: enable-pop-over in the HTML I would have it default to true. Does that provide the additional context needed?

Comment: @Claies you're feeling is right but the problem is not directly in the code but the fact that enablePopOver is probably not two-ways bindable, which cause the error when it is supposed to get updated. I think I'll post an answer anyway

Comment: @floribon the OP just stated that the property didn't exist as an HTML Attribute, which is exactly my point.

Comment: @Zigrivers I'm not asking for enablePopOver but simply the directive myPopOver. You use it somewhere otherwise it wouldn't crash

Comment: @floribon Let me see if I can set up a jsbin with a working example. You guys are awesome to help me with understanding this - I really appreciate it. Should have something put together I can share in a few mins.

Comment: @Claies your intuition was correct and maybe it is just a formulation problem but your answer was misleading and some statements were not true, hope you understand

Comment: I guess I just don't understand how my answer was any different; I may have worded it wrong, but what I was trying to say all along is that if you have a property on the isolate scope that is `undefined`, it doesn't exist in `$scope` and can't be assigned to.

Comment: @Claies Ok I get your point but it would be more accurate to say "if you have a property that is defined as a two-way binding that is undefined, it cannot be updated from the link phase". Otherwise it sounds like you cannot extend an isolated scope. The problem is really the two-way binding here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `enablePopOver` as a two-ways binding in your directive definition (using `'='`). However you say in a comment that this property is not always there, which means you cannot define a two-ways binding on something that doesn't exist!

The easiest way to fix that is to always rely on a boolean variable in your html

```
<div my-pop-over enable-pop-over="isEnabled">
```

And initialize your scope in the controller with `$scope.isEnabled = false`

---

Another way to fix the issue if you really want to handle the case when the attribte is missing but still simulate a two-way binding is to remove this line:

```
enablePopOver       : '='
```

And instead watch the attribute directly in the link function (however since the scope is isolated your need to watch over the parent):

```
if (iAttrs.enablePopOver) {
  $scope.$parent.$watch(iAttrs.enablePopOver, function(enabled) {
    $scope.enablePopOver = enabled;
  });
}
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxttbpts/1/

---

There are even more ways to work around it. Using the `{{}}` notation, `$observe` the attribute, maybe even use a service, etc etc.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and that helps me better understand what's going on with this issue. Thank you!